# Chrome Path File Issue (Not Personal Issue) while using the Webbrowser Module

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

So I recently wrote a small code to enter a specific URL using webbrowser module. And it worked on my PC. But when I ran the same code on my friend's PC, the webbrowser module failed to open Chrome. Here is my code:

```
import webbrowser

url = 'https://pythonexamples.org'
webbrowser.register('chrome',None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C://Program Files(x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
webbrowser.get('chrome').open(url)
```

So on doing some research, we found out that the **issue was with the Program Files(x86)**. The reason why Chrome opened up on my pc is because the **Google folder was stored in Program Files(x86) and Program Files on my friend's PC.** So my intention is to create a solution for this so that my function runs on any pc without having to worry about this path issue.

On googling we found this info:

*Starting soon, Google Chrome will install in the C:\Program Files\ folder by default on Windows if it is a 64-bit installer. Chrome 64-bit versions installed in the C:\Program Files (x86)\ folder will continue to work and will be updated just like before.*

So **how do we create a code where first we can determine whether the Google folder is in Program Files or Program Files(x86) and then register the path file in webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser parameter**. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance:)

Update: My new code based on Markus Rosjat's solution

```
def get_executable(search_path, executeable_name):
    for sdir, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
        if executeable_name in files:
            exe = files[files.index(executeable_name)]
            return os.path.join(sdir, exe)

for path in [ 'C:\\program files',"C:\\program files(x86)"]:
    exe = get_executable(path, 'chrome.exe')
    if exe:
        url = f'https://{website}.com'
        webbrowser.register('chr', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(exe))
        webbrowser.get('chr').open(url)
```

The code isn't returning any thing as such.

Comment: if you plan to run it only on windows you could use the `windows-default` to register a browser. This should open the default browser of the system. but on a side note even without an register should webbrowser open the default browser on your system

Comment: @Markus Rosjat Thank you. Yes, I only plan to run on windows. Sorry if I misunderstood what you meant but the problem is mainly about the path file. What I want is each time I use my function, I really don't want to cross-check whether the Google folder (which contains chrome.exe) is present in Program Files or Program Files(x86). If you don't mind please kindly post your code or explain in detail so that I can understand better:) Also setting Chrome as default isn't what I want as my solution. Is there any other way?

Comment: well just try to comment out your register line in the code and run it again. It should work still since the webbrowser module should attempt to open the default browser of the system.

Comment: @markus Rosjat Sure Ill try that and tell you:)

Comment: Nope, it didn't work rather raised an error.
 raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

Comment: another question to your code, are you sure you want the backgroundBrowser? Anyway i will post a smal function that could get you to your browser path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to short example on the comments above

```
import webbrowser

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
webbrowser.open(url)
```

should try to attempt to open the  default browser on a system. If you wanna use register try the `windows-default` option

a good tarting point shoould be https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

**Update**

you could get a controller for the browser you want, well the bowser needs to be installed on the system.

```
import webbrowser

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
controller = webbrowser.get('chrome')
controller.open(url)
```

if you look in the doc you could iterate over all the possible presets for the get method and use the first controller you get but that might be a little to much. If you are sure there is a chrome then the lines above should be enough.

Update for a simple function to find the path to an executable, it should be ok for this use.

```
import os

def get_executable(search_path, executeable_name):
    for sdir,dir,files in os.walk(search_path):
        if executeable_name in files:
            exe = files[files.index(executeable_name)]
            return os.path.join(sdir,exe)

exe = get_executable('C:\\program files', 'chrome.exe')
```

**Update for a simply iteration over a list of paths**

this is a quick n dirty example

```
for path in ['C:\\program files(x86)', 'C:\\program files']:
    exe = get_executable(path, 'opera.exe')
    if exe:
        break
```

you can put as many paths in the list as you like to search in for your exe file

**Update for more explicit failure**

again this is just an example, its not intended to be very useful but it gives an idea how to go about things. The aim isnt that I solve the problem, its to give you directions to investigate further ;)

```
import os
import webbrowser


class BrowserNotFoundException(Exception):
    pass


def get_executable(search_path, executable_name):
    for sdir, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
        if executable_name in files:
            exe = files[files.index(executable_name)]
            return os.path.join(sdir,exe)

def search_paths(paths, executable_name):
    for path in paths:
        exe = get_executable(path, executable_name)
        if exe:
            return exe
    raise BrowserNotFoundException(f'{executable_name} is not in the path searched({paths})')

paths =  ['c:\\program files(x86)', 'c:\\program files']
executable = 'chrome.exe'
url = 'https://google.com'


exe = search_paths(paths,executable)
webbrowser.register('myBrowser', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(exe))
webbrowser.get('myBrowser').open(url)
```

cheers

MArkus

Comment: Thank you Markus but this doesn't open in Chrome Browse . and rather opens in windows explorer for me. I specifically want chrome browser as it is the most widely used.

Comment: i updated the code so you see an example for a controller object.

Comment: @ Markus Rosjat Oh nice but the thing is now in a case if chrome.exe is present in Program Files(x86), this code won't return anything I believe (as I tried it too). So is there a way like by which we can first search in the program files and if it doesn't exist there, then search in Program files(x86)? – Hrishi 8 mins ago

Comment: well you can use the little function i posted to look in both paths or any path you like to search. you simply have to write some code to iterate over a list of paths to search for example and as soon you have a  hit simply  stop searching

Comment: one thing to think about with the register function, i noticed if you register a name that is a preset it might not work as expected so maybe consider to use register not with 'chrome' and instead some other name and change the get call accodringly

Comment: Yes sir I understood your solution and tried it but unfortunately still isn't working. I can't post my code here so Ill edit the question.

Comment: Sir in place of if exe, would **os.path.exists** work here? I am really new to os module, that's the thing. I only learned the os module yesterday when you posted your update solution which I am very thankful for:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236552/discussion-between-hrishi-and-markus-rosjat).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sensei. I think I can take it from here. You truly are a great teacher and the **friendliest sensei in StackOverflow** (with no doubts). Will never forget the help you have done to guide me in this direction. Cheers, have a great day ahead:)

Comment: You are welcome, most people have forgotten how they started and often don't realize that there are people out there that are not at the same lvl as they are. I try to remind myself of that when i post here but i struggle too. Gald I cold help a little, take care